# Double click word doesn't select it

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, input-methods

I'd a Samsung Galaxy I5510 with stock rom, android 2.2. Whenever I double-clicked any word in an input field it got selected. Now I bought a Samsung Galaxy Ace I still have stock rom and andrond 2.3.4 and double-clicking a word does nothing. Is there any way I can get this functionality back? It was very useful to add words to swype after typing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this functionality lays on the keyboard. I'd and old version of Swype (which came installed). After rooting, I followed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1154334) instructions to update Swype and now I get this functionality back. Good luck to everyone!